# How to change key + secret group values loop in php?

Tags: php, loops

**How to change key + secret values loop in php?**

I have the following values:

```
$key1 = '111111111';
$key2 = '222222222';   
$secret1 = '1111111111111111111111111'; 
$secret2 = '2222222222222222222222222';
```

How to change key + secret group

```
$access_key = '111111111';
$access_secret = '1111111111111111111111111';
```

loop

```
$access_key = '222222222';
$access_secret = '2222222222222222222222222';
```

Note: not show

```
$access_key = '1111111111';
$access_secret = '2222222222222222222222222';
```

Comment: Look into using arrays.

Answer (score 0):

A simple array of keys and secrets allows you to do this...

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$key = ['111111111','222222222'];
$secret = ['1111111111111111111111111','2222222222222222222222222'];

for ( $i = 0; $i < count($key); $i++ )  {
    $access_key = $key[$i];
    $access_secret = $secret[$i];

    echo $access_key."->".$access_secret.PHP_EOL;
}
```

So first create 2 arrays, one with the key and then a matching array with the secrets.  The loop takes each key and the corresponding secret using $i.

This outputs -

```
111111111->1111111111111111111111111
222222222->2222222222222222222222222
```

Comment: I appreciate your support. However, what I want is when echo out will be displayed in all group text:

`$ access_key = '111111111';
$ access_secret = '1111111111111111111111111';`

After reloading, the page displays only the group

`$ access_key = '222222222';
$ access_secret = '2222222222222222222222222';`

and repeat loop on load page